# How to Add/Remove items to ComboBox Collection?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to remove selected item from ComboBox Collection:
Items are added manually, as a Collection, in design time.
buttonClick:

```
cb01.Items.Remove(cb01.SelectedItem);.
```

This deletes the item, but next time I open the Form - the item appears again.
Must I have a database for 5-6 items ?
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `cb01.Items.Remove(cb01.SelectedItem);` will only remove from the combobox, not from the datasource binded to the combobox. You may remove it from the datasource and re bind the source.

If you are binding the combobox with an array in your code, then you may save the array on a persistent storage, either a database table, or XML file and upon deletion from combobox you should remove the element from the array and save the changes to the persistent storage

Comment: But the data source is a collection writen in design time. How could I remove and add items in this collection ?

Comment: @Buena, you can't , without using any persistent storage, you may save it to an xml file and then modify the xml file to your needs

Comment: Are you sure? I must have separate file in order to manipulate 5-6 items? What is then the purpose of Items property of a ComboBox?

Comment: @Buena, yes I am pretty sure, ItemCollection property doesn't hold the information upon application close. It is maintained in the memory

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with Files (existing in System.IO Namespace) if you don't want to use a database server. for 5/6 items it's not worth to use database, and in a file you can easily find the item's line and delete the line.
hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll try with dataset and xml.